# Power set and set of all mappings

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working with the Terence Tao's Analysis book. And I have a question in the part of set theory.

As power set axiom, Tao use the set of all function: "If X, and Y be sets. Then there exist a set which consist of all the functions from X to Y."

Using that axiom and the replacement axiom, I need to prove:

"Let X be a set. Then $$ \left \{ A : A \subseteq X \right \} \ $$  is a set"

I have worked in the next way, but I'm not satisfy with the result:

$$ Let\: \; P(X) : = \left \{ A : A\subseteq X  \right \} $$ 
$$\ g: \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{X}\rightarrow  P(X)$$
$$ \forall f \left ( f \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{X} \wedge g(f) := f^{-1} [\,  \left \{ 1 \right \} \, ]  \right )  $$

Then, using the axiom of replacement and the axiom of power set (as the book use it) I get the next:

$$ G: = \left \{ g(f) :  f \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{X}   \right \} $$

And I supposed that I need: G = P(X)

Therefore 
$$ A \in  G \leftrightarrow  f[A] = \left \{ 1 \right \} $$

And to  some B be in P(X), we have: $$ B\in P(X) \leftrightarrow B \subseteq X $$ and as the images conserves the inclusion  $$ f [B] \subseteq f[X] $$

I thought that only I needed to show it $$ f [A] \subseteq f[X] $$  but I'm stack here, so my approach was the next:

$$\bigcup_{f\in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{X} } f [X] = \left \{ 0,1 \right \} $$

$$ f[A] \subseteq \bigcup_{f\in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{X} } f [X] $$

and in other exercise I proved that the image conserves the union, so "I can conclude something a little odd (haha)"

$$ A\subseteq \bigcup X = X $$

I really don't feel comfortable with the result and also I don't know how to show :

$$ P(X)\subseteq G $$

(sorry for my mistakes, the English is not my mother language).

My question is indeed how can I prove that?

Comment: What is it that you're not satisfied with? That's the usual way of establishing a correspondence $2^X \simeq \mathscr P(X)$. In fact, what is your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: When you say, "Let $P(X)=\dots$," how do you know you can do that? And if you defining a class rather than a set, how can you define $g$ as a function with a class as its target?

Comment: You are on the right track, but probably want $P(X):=\{ f^{-1}[\{1\}]\mid f\in \{0,1\}^X\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Andrews The exercise is indeed show that P(X) is a set. Assuming only as a power set, the set of all function, and the axiom of replacement. So, I don't know. some hint?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen in this context is arbitrary use the inverse map of the set {1} instead of {0}. The book didn't speak about it, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Not having the book in front of me, I don't know the axioms. The construction of $g$ just struck me as problematic. (Often, mathematicians can tell what is wrong with a proof without knowing how to fix it. :) )

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hehehe, the first axiom is the above call it as power axiom (I think is other version that the normal one use it in almost every book and notes I have seen before).

And the other one is the axiom of replacement, which the author write as follow: "Let A be a set. For any object  in A, and any object y, suppose we have the statement  P(x,y) pertaining to x and y, such that for each x in A there is at most one y for which P(x,y) is true. Then there exist a set {y: P(x,y) is true for some x in A}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot begin by letting $\wp(X)=\{A:A\subseteq X\}$, because you don’t yet know that this object exists: that’s what you’re trying to prove. You do, however, know that $\{0,1\}^X$ exists. Let $\varphi(x,y)$ be the following formula:

$$\left(x\in\{0,1\}^X\land y=x^{-1}[\{1\}]\right)\lor\left(x\notin\{0,1\}^X\land y=0\right)$$

Then $\varphi(x,y)$ is functional: $\forall x\exists!y\,\varphi(x,y)$. Now you can apply replacement to conclude that there is a set $G$ such that

$$y\in G\leftrightarrow\exists x\in\{0,1\}^X\,\varphi(x,y)\;,$$

i.e., $$y\in G\leftrightarrow\exists f\in\{0,1\}^X\left(y=f^{-1}\big[\{1\}\big]\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

It remains to show that $\forall y(y\in G\leftrightarrow y\subseteq X)$, i.e., that this set $G$ really **is** the power set of $X$.

It’s straightforward to see that $\forall y(y\in G\to y\subseteq X)$. For the other implication, suppose that $y\subseteq X$, and define a function $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ that demonstrates (using $(1)$) that $y\in G$.

Comment: Thanks, I need to take a moment and think  with detail in all the steps:)

Comment: I don't understand the last point. If $$ y\subseteq X \; and\; f: X\rightarrow \left \{ 0,1 \right \} $$ It is obvious that f is in the set define above, the set of all functions maps X into {0,1}, but It's not clear for me that, if $$ y\subseteq X \rightarrow y\in G $$ as the definition says, if $$ y\in G\leftrightarrow y =f^{-1} [\left \{ 1 \right \}]\leftrightarrow f[y] = \left \{ 1 \right \} $$ but what's happen if f maps Y only in {0} ? (sorry, maybe it is a kinda stupid question but I don't get it :P)

Comment: I think I got it: if f is defined as follow: if f is 1 when some x is in Y and is 0 if x is not in Y (It's a characteristic function, right?) I'm happy :D

Comment: @user84164: Yes, you got it: you want to define $f$ to be the characteristic function of $y$, and then you have $y=f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ and therefore $y\in G$ by $(1)$.

Comment: Hi again, before all thanks. I have a little question: is it possible to establish a collection of partial function between a set X into Y and show it is a set, only with generate a set consisting: $$ \left\{ y^{x}: y\in P(Y) \wedge x\in P(X) \right\} $$ or is too naive to do that :P?

Comment: @user84164: Yes, you can do that. You’re given the existence of $y^x$ for any sets $x$ and $y$, and we’ve just proved that each set has a power set; with these facts and the axiom schema of comprehension we can immediately construct $$\left\{y^x:y\in\wp(Y)\land x\in\wp(X)\right\}\;.$$

Comment: I really appreciate it :). So, I can form a set whose members of their members are partial function from X to Y, and only using the axiom of union I get the set of all the partial function from those sets. I think I get it :D